# Возвращение обьектов через map() JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив строк `proposals`

Хочу создать новый массив на основе `proposals`, где элементами массива должны быть обьекты, а элементы первоначального массива должны стать значениями поля `name` для 
соответствующих обьектов.
Использую:
 `proposalsObject = this.state.proposals.map((proposal, index) =>{name: proposal, id: index, votesCount: 0 })`

Тем не менее выдает ошибку, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нужны круглые скобки вокруг фигурных: `=>({name: proposal, id: index, votesCount: 0 })`

Comment: сейчас дубликат поищу